# How to get a ColorPalette object?

Tags: c#, gdi+

This class has no constructor, I am wondering how to get a ColorPalette object?

Comment: `Palette` has two `t` but just one `l`

Comment: Create a dummy bitmap with the right pixel format to get one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colorpalette.aspx):

> You are not allowed to construct a ColorPalette object directly. If
>   you created a ColorPalette object, you could then manipulate the
>   palette size for a particular image, which is not allowed. Use the
>   Image.Palette property to obtain a ColorPalette object.